# a href messes css animation

Tags: css, image, animation, href

i made css animated banner, result can be seen here
http://nikatest.dlinkddns.com/webs/ypic/
the problem is that to some pictures i want to add a href link and when i do it messes up animation, first picture got a href attribute and you can see its smaller and isnt fitted into same length div as others here is html code:

```
<header class="mainheader">

<div>
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/camera.jpg" alt="camerra"/>
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/girl.jpg" alt="asian student"/>
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/kids.jpg" alt="campus kids"/>
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/books.jpg" alt="books" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/lemuelinchrist/2657001395/'" />
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/field.jpg" alt="cambridge" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/ericatkins/7927420108/'" />
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/icl.jpg" alt="icl" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/herry/2924207957/'" />
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/math.jpg" alt="math" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/featheredtar/76976279/'"/>
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/student.jpg" alt="student" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/merchau/8548057127/'"/>
<img class='photo'  src="temp/temp/img/cut/ucl.jpg" alt="ucl" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/stevecadman/371199372/'"/>



</div>
<!--  <img src="temp/img/logo.gif">-->
</header>


</body>
```

and my css file ypicstyle.css in temp folder looks like this:

```
.mainheader div/*.container*/{
/*margin:50px auto;*/
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
margin: 2% 0;
/*width:500px;
height:300px;*/
overflow:hidden;
border:0px solid;
border-top-color:#856036;
border-left-color:#5d4426;
border-bottom-color:black;
border-right-color:#5d4426;
position:relative;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.photo{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:auto;
-webkit-animation:round 36s infinite;
-moz-animation:round 36s infinite;
-ms-animation:round 36s infinite;
-o-animation:round 36s infinite;
animation:round 36s infinite;
opacity:0;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;

}

@keyframes round{
11.1%{opacity:1;}
/*25%{opacity:1;} */
22.2%{opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes round{
11.1%{opacity:1;}
22.2%{opacity:0;}
}
img:nth-child(1){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
-moz-animation-delay:0s;
-ms-animation-delay:0s;
-o-animation-delay:0s;
animation-delay:0s;
}
img:nth-child(2){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:4s;
-moz-animation-delay:4s;
-ms-animation-delay:4s;
-o-animation-delay:4s;
animation-delay:4s;
}
img:nth-child(3){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:8s;
-moz-animation-delay:8s;
-ms-animation-delay:8s;
-o-animation-delay:8s;
animation-delay:8s;
}
img:nth-child(4){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:12s;
-moz-animation-delay:12s;
-ms-animation-delay:12s;
-o-animation-delay:12s;
animation-delay:15s;
}
img:nth-child(5){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:16s;
-moz-animation-delay:16s;
-ms-animation-delay:16s;
-o-animation-delay:16s;
animation-delay:16s;
}

img:nth-child(6){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:20s;
-moz-animation-delay:20s;
-ms-animation-delay:20s;
-o-animation-delay:20s;
animation-delay:20s;
}

img:nth-child(7){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:24s;
-moz-animation-delay:24s;
-ms-animation-delay:24s;
-o-animation-delay:24s;
animation-delay:24s;
}

img:nth-child(8){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:28s;
-moz-animation-delay:28s;
-ms-animation-delay:28s;
-o-animation-delay:28s;
animation-delay:28s;
}

img:nth-child(9){
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:32s;
-moz-animation-delay:32s;
-ms-animation-delay:32s;
-o-animation-delay:32s;
animation-delay:32s;
}
/*<<<<<slider end>>>>>>>>>>*/

body {
/*    background-image: url('img/bg.jpg'); */
color: #000305; /*mostly black*/
font-size: 87.5%; /*base font size is 14px */
font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
line-height: 1.5;
text-allign: left;
background-color: #fff;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
color: #26a4fb;
}

a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #26a4fb;
color: #FFF;
}

.body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
clear: both;
}

.mainheader img {
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
margin: 2% 0; 
}

.mainheader nav {
background-color: #FFF;
opacity: 0.8;
height: 120px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

/*menu icon*/
#menu-icon {
display: none;
width: 10px;
height: 15px;
/*background: url('img/menu.jpg');
/*opacity: 0.1;*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Im trying to format it properly in here for half an hour but doesnt seems to be working...
so are anyone having suggestions how to i can implement links to my pictures without it having any effect on css animation? thank you all::::
:::::edit:::::
okey can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? maybe i have animation timing off, maybe that and something else, but im getting really frustrated as you can see if you try the url of example, some pictures dont have link,and some do but whenever i click on any of the pictures it sends me to the link of the last one..can someone help please?

Comment: You can add an `onclick="location.href='url'"` to the images that need links. Almost all elements (in modern browsers) can have a click event, hover effect etc.)

Comment: this is not working its still giving me the same link, no matter if 1st or 5th picture displayed still it is fist link that is sending me to after click :-/ still dont have solution... but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should also add width: inherit and height: inherit to  element, and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the anchor like this:

```
<a class='photo img1' href=''></a>
<a class='photo img2' href=''></a>

.photo {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(image-link);
}

.photo.img1 {
    background-image: url(image-link-1);
}
.photo.img2 {
    background-image: url(image-link-2);
}
```

Comment: okey but how to then make animation go link after link i dont have a clue....anyway, still looking and trying, thank you

Comment: @joural I'm facing the exact same issue. Clicking on the link takes me to last link of the collection.